# Not getting emails from ExceptionNotifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I followed this [tutorial](http://svn.rubyonrails.org/rails/plugins/exception_notification/README) on configuring the Rails plugin ExceptionNotifier.

I know that I have ActionMailer configured correctly because I am getting mail from other forms. I even have local_addresses.clear set so that it should be delivering mail no matter what.

I am using Apache with a mongrel_cluster running in the backend.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added your ExceptionNotifier configuration information (your email address, etc.) into config/environment.rb, did you add it within the Rails::Initializer block or did you add it at the end of the file?

The tutorial you linked to doesn't specify *where* in the environment file to put the configuration information.  The tutorial I followed (which might have been [this one](http://internetducttape.com/2008/02/06/rails-guide-exception-notifier-plugin/)) does specify to put it outside the block.

Which things go inside that block and which outside is, frankly, still a little mysterious to me.  But I thought this might answer your specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the SVN version of the plugin, which is probably unmaintained. [Latest version can be found here](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/master).

Second thing which you can do is check the production log. Mailings get written to the log, so you'll see if Rails ever even *tried* to send it. If there are no entries, that means things are silently failing, which probably happens because -- for some reason -- exceptions are not caught properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check your production log, exceptions can be throw in side the exception_notifier plugin, which prevent it from sending mails